# Does CLI mean anything other than "command line interface"?

Tags: f#, command-line-interface

According to Wikipedia, on the Comparison of programming languages page, it says that F# uses CLI. Does that mean that F# is designed for the purpose of making command-line applications and not graphical applications, or is there another meaning of CLI?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in .NET it's the Common Language Infrastructure.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure

Answer (score 11):

The Wikipedia lists several meanings of CLI:

> - Command line interface (computer tech interaction)
> - Command line interpreter (command line shell)
> - Call Level Interface (an SQL database management API)
> - Common Language Infrastructure (a Microsoft .NET Framework specification)
> - CLI (x86 instruction)

Comment: Given that the question related to F#, Common Language Infrastructure (a Microsoft .NET Framework specification) is the only meaningful answer there.  The rest is just lowering the signal to noise ratio.

Answer (score 4):

[Common Language Infrastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure)?

Answer (score 3):

Common Language Infrastructure/Interpreter. It's talking about Bytecode.

Answer (score -2):

Customer Loyalty Initiative - several companies use this to index themselves against their peers for improving/encouraging repeat business.

More items listedon Acronym Finder: http://www.acronymfinder.com/CLI.html